# How to create an iPhone app that interacts with my website?

Tags: iphone

What I want to do is to make an iPhone application for my website similar to the [photofunia](http://photofunia.com/). The users will be able to select an effect from a list, and then upload their own photo. Then the result will be shown in the browser where the user can save the image and/or publish to website like facebook, etc.

What software can I use to do that? [Phonegap](http://www.phonegap.com/), [appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/), etc? Can some of these help?

Thanks.

Comment: The first step is to learn how to spell “iPhone” (I've corrected your title).

Comment: The second step is to purchase a OSX computer.

Comment: The fourth step is to profit!

Comment: I know I know, `[old|tired] meme is [old|tired]`. I couldn't help myself :p

Comment: @drachenstern: It's OK, but you just had to do it wrong. It's ???? not ..... :P

Comment: @BoltClock oh crap! what was I thinking? (for reference: I was thinking "get in b4 someone posts behind you and spoils it")

Comment: Witch software cannot help, I'm sorry. Witches cannot program.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you may be able to make an iPhone app using Adobe Flash and the Adobe Packager for iPhone.

The other option is to get a Mac and Learn Objective-C.

There is no "easy" solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Create a webservice for your website and try to use that in your iPhone Application

Answer (score 0):

Of course I know there is no "easy" solution, but I'm almost sure there are other options for making iphone apps, instead of using Objective-C. 
I only don't know the name of the tools.
Flash doesn't works. Adobe Air currently doesn't offer a way to access the camera roll on the ios.